# image to have position at bottom of div but remain fixed after scrolling

Tags: css, image, scroll, position

I think I have seen this before but what Im after is this:

I have two divs side by side.  Both are variable length depending on user choices.  Basically all I want is to have a logo appear at the bottom of the left div.  If the right div is longer and ends up scrolling past the left div, I want the logo that was at the bottom of the left div to fix itself at the top if the user scrolls beyond the bottom of the left div.  I dont know if Im saying it right...but thats what I want!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want something like this:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">

</div>

<script>
$('.right').scroll(
   function(){
    var logoOffset = $('.logo').offset();

    if(logoOffset.top < window.pageYOffset) 
     {$('.logo').css({'position':'fixed', 'top': '0'});}
    else 
     {$('.logo').css({'position':'absolute', 'bottom': '0'});}
   }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a "sticky footer".

- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/